# Return value of stopping tomcat service on minions

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8, salt-stack

I try to restart the tomcat service on the minion with the command " salt ' * ' cmd.run 'service tomcat8080 stop' " / " salt '*' cmd.run 'service tomcat8080 start' " (without double quotation)
The returner on the screen shows as below:
[image]

I don't know why these results are different, and the tomcat on minions configured all right. 
And the results of TEST1 & 4 are what I expected.
Besides, results of starting tomcat are the same.
I also checked the log file and is said "The Salt Master has cached the public key for this node, this salt minion will wait for 10 seconds before attempting to re-authenticate"
So I clear the cache folder (/var/cache/salt/master/minion/), kill the daemons of master and minion and delete the file in /etc/salt/pki/ then restart both master and minion, but it doesn't work
Any solutions to this problem?
Thx guys!

Comment: Ok,first think that comes to mind is not trying to restart it with `cmd.run`,instead do it with `salt 'target' service.restart tomcat8080` .I haven't done anything with tomcat in salt but you sure about the 8080?

Comment: That helps a lot, but service.restart command returned False, so I need to stop service.stop first then service.start

Comment: it is solved now?if it is do you want me to post my idea as an answer?

Comment: Not yet, but your idea offers me another way to restart tomcat service. Of course you can post it as an answer. But I hope someone can offer a solution in my situation.